# Accepting a Discord Invite using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to create a simple script to accept a Discord Invite. I've managed to login to an account however I cannot get it to accept the invite.

I've tried using the XPath aswell as using CSS selector to try and find the button but i'm having no luck (examples seen below).

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/section/div/button")

browser.find_element_by_class_name('marginTop40-i-78cZ.button-3k0cO7.button-38aScr.lookFilled-1Gx00P.colorBrand-3pXr91.sizeLarge-1vSeWK.fullWidth-1orjjo.grow-q77ONN')
```

The outer html is:

```
<button type="button" class="marginTop40-Q4o1tS button-1cRKG6 button-f2h6uQ lookFilled-yCfaCM colorBrand-I6CyqQ sizeLarge-3mScP9 fullWidth-fJIsjq grow-2sR_-F"><div class="contents-3ca1mk">Accept Invite</div></button>
```

Full XPath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/button
```

I've attached a discord invite link at the bottom of the page as an example.

Any help would be much appreciated.

https://discord.com/invite/the1

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've attached 2 examples of trials, been going at it for a few hours now haha.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the _`accept the invite`_ element.

Comment: Just added both the HTML and the Full XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='button'] > div[class^='contents']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button/div[starts-with(@class, 'contents') and text()='Accept Invite']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```